Can I extract/bake the collisions generated by a tilemap collider?
Given a tilemap, with a tilemap collider, is it possible to extract/bake the current collision(s) onto a separate gameobject independent from the tilemap/tilemap collider?
My 2D game streams a large tiled world, and the only data I can't afford to offload is collisions due to pathfinding. I would like to have a loading screen where I load each tilemap sector, extract the collisions, and offload the sector - so at the beginning my world is just bunch of collision data with no actual tilemaps.
I don't want to keep collision-only tilemaps loaded because I think they still allocate the full array for all tiles when most likely the world will be sparse.

For very long-range pathfinding, your own data structure is probably a more scalable solution than relying on physics colliders.

@DMGregory yes, however I'm making heavy use of a pathfinding asset that has no way of updating its node graph without letting it scan for colliders.
